# Jquery mega drop down loading after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, megamenu

There may not be a fix for this. I am using a jquery drop down menu that loads when the DOM is ready. From what I understand this means it waits until the page is fully loaded until it becomes ready to be used.

This is problematic for a menu system because people want to use the menu right away often before the entire page is loaded.

Here is my site where you can see this happening.
http://bit.ly/g1sn5t

This is my script that I am using for the menu

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


    function megaHoverOver(){
        $(this).find(".sub").stop().fadeTo('fast', 1).show();

        //Calculate width of all ul's
        (function($) { 
            jQuery.fn.calcSubWidth = function() {
                rowWidth = 0;
                //Calculate row
                $(this).find("ul").each(function() {                    
                    rowWidth += $(this).width(); 
                }); 
            };
        })(jQuery); 

        if ( $(this).find(".row").length > 0 ) { //If row exists...
            var biggestRow = 0; 
            //Calculate each row
            $(this).find(".row").each(function() {                             
                $(this).calcSubWidth();
                //Find biggest row
                if(rowWidth > biggestRow) {
                    biggestRow = rowWidth;
                }
            });
            //Set width
            $(this).find(".sub").css({'width' :biggestRow});
            $(this).find(".row:last").css({'margin':'0'});

        } else { //If row does not exist...

            $(this).calcSubWidth();
            //Set Width
            $(this).find(".sub").css({'width' : rowWidth});

        }
    }

    function megaHoverOut(){ 
      $(this).find(".sub").stop().fadeTo('fast', 0, function() {
          $(this).hide(); 
      });
    }


    var config = {    
         sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
         interval: 0, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
         over: megaHoverOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
         timeout: 0, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
         out: megaHoverOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
    };

    $("ul#topnav li .sub").css({'opacity':'0'});
    $("ul#topnav li").hoverIntent(config);



});

function clearText(field){

    if (field.defaultValue == field.value) field.value = '';
    else if (field.value == '') field.value = field.defaultValue;

}




// JavaScript Document
```

Is there anyway to get this to load before everything else?

Comment: That's why you build a functional menu first and then layer JS on top of it. You could try putting the JS just underneath the menu part and not wrap it in a `.ready` call

Comment: I know it's been 11 years but what was the solution?  Problem still happening with megamenu in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You can put those scripts wherever you whant in the case of understanding exactly what you are doing.
HTML are rendered sequentially, so scripts cannot get the DOM object or js variables defined later in the document. That's why we usually use document onload event to do the init thing since all elements are loaded.

In this case, I guess you can probably put the scripts without document.ready right after the closing of ul#topnav tag.

Comment: I just tried using the script without the document.ready and the drop downs stopped working entirely. The javascript for it is already one of the first things called in the sequential order.